# How can I go into osgi console again after I have started my carbon.sh

Tags: wso2

first , If a microservice bundle is started ,like this "./carbon.sh --start", then , I want to go to the osgi console again.
How can I go into it? If I go into osgi console by ./carbon.sh ,it  will prompt the port is already used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it. But you can use [`screen`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen) command here.

Answer (score 0):

when you run the server with `./carbon.sh --start` it will start the server in nohup mode. So why you wanna access OSGi Console in nohup mode?
If you want to access the OSGi console just start the server with `./carbon.sh` command

Comment: There is a Scenes that  I want to go into the osgi console and check some bundles after I start the msf4j server.  so I hope that there is a way to go into console